# PHP - How Can I make this array work?

Tags: php, html, arrays, image

So I've got an array, which gets random images and display them with certain text. Unfortunately, the text won't appear and the if it does, the hyperlink doesn't appear UNDER  the image. Please someone help!!

```
<?php
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT', 3);
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT', '<img src="%s"><a href="%s"> alt="%s" title="%3$s"   style="margin-right:10px"></a>');

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$images = array (
    array ( 'title' => 'Test 2', 'src' => 'pic2.jpg', 'href' => '<a href=http://mylink.com/path/>Click Me</a>' ),
    array ( 'title' => 'Test 3', 'src' => 'pic3.jpg', 'href' => '<a href=http://mylink.com/path/>Click Me</a>' ),
    array ( 'title' => 'Test 4', 'src' => 'pic4.jpg', 'href' => '<a     href=http://mylink.com/path/>Click Me</a>' )
);

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if ( count($images) < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT ) {
    trigger_error('Not enough images given', E_USER_WARNING);
    exit;
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for ($i = 0; $i < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT; $i++) {
    shuffle($images);

    $tmp = array_shift($images);
    printf( RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT, $tmp['src'],$tmp['href'], $tmp['title'] );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the positioning of your link under the image, you'd have to work on your CSS. For proper working of the code sample, make following changes:

1. Update `RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT` to

   ```
   define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT', '<img src="%s" /><a href="%s" alt="%s" title="%s" style="margin-right:10px">Click Me</a>');
   ```
2. Change the array to:

   ```
   $images = array (
       array ( 'title' => 'Test 2', 'src' => 'pic2.jpg', 'href' => 'http://mylink.com/path/' ),
       array ( 'title' => 'Test 3', 'src' => 'pic3.jpg', 'href' => 'http://mylink.com/path/' ),
       array ( 'title' => 'Test 4', 'src' => 'pic4.jpg', 'href' => 'http://mylink.com/path/' )
   );
   ```
3. Use `printf` like this:

   ```
   printf( RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT, $tmp['src'], $tmp['href'], $tmp['title'], $tmp['title'] );
   ```

Comment: The code is good :) however, I don't want "click me" for every image, each image has a unique qoute, so is that possible?

Comment: @KaRoLis Add another index in array, let's say `text`. Replace `Click Me` in `RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT` with `%s` and pass `$tmp['text']` as a fifth parameter in `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code have multiple issues:

Constant `RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT` is poorly formatted as HTML it should look like:

```
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT', '<img src="%s" alt="%s" title="%3$s"   style="margin-right:10px"><a href="%s"></a>');
```

As for that, the order of printf arguments should be reordered, because we have modified displaying them in `RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT`:

```
printf( RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT, $tmp['src'],$tmp['href'], $tmp['title'] );
```

In your `$images` array, links should be only URL, not full links, as you defined then already in `RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT`.

Full code you presented should look like this:

```
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT', 3);
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT', '<img src="%s"  alt="%s" title="%3$s"   style="margin-right:10px"><a href="%s"></a>');

$images = array (
    array ( 'title' => 'Test 2', 'src' => 'pic2.jpg', 'href' => 'http://mylink.com/path/' ),
    array ( 'title' => 'Test 3', 'src' => 'pic3.jpg', 'href' => 'http://mylink.com/path/' ),
    array ( 'title' => 'Test 4', 'src' => 'pic4.jpg', 'href' => 'http://mylink.com/path/' )
);


if ( count($images) < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT ) {
    trigger_error('Not enough images given', E_USER_WARNING);
    exit;
}


for ($i = 0; $i < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT; $i++) {
    shuffle($images);

    $tmp = array_shift($images);
    printf( RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT, $tmp['src'],$tmp['href'], $tmp['title'] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="%s"><a href="%s"> alt="%s" title="%3$s"   style="margin-right:10px"></a>
```

do not close the tag a after href="%s"
and put img inside of a tag, like this:

```
<a><img/></a>
```

Comment: so you're saying like this?

<img src="%s"><a href="%s"<a><img/></a>> alt="%s" title="%3$s"   style="margin-right:10px"></a>

Comment: It seems to me that the structure i proposed is more suitable for such situations, but if you need it your way, just check the markup of the given html

Comment: <a href="%s" title="%s" style="margin-right:10px"><img src="%s" alt="%s"></a>
and correct the arguments order in print-function

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
 define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT', '<img src="%s"><a href="%s"> alt="%s" title="%3$s"   style="margin-right:10px"></a>');
```

and

```
 array ( 'title' => 'Test 2', 'src' => 'pic2.jpg', 'href' => '<a href=http://mylink.com/path/>Click Me</a>' ),
```

their is a problem with `href` try to give only link in `href`